# Adapt to Integrer value

Tags: java, android, seekbar

i'm developing an BMI calculator and i'm having some troubles eith formats on an EditText

The following code i an adaptantion from another seekbar which has a float value. But this new one has an int value. Could someone tell me what should i change to adapt this code to integrer.

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener alterarpesoListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
    boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Calcula o novo valor do TIP

        int setPeso = (alterarPeso.getProgress());
        // mostra na caixa o valor novo
        editPeso.setText(String.format("%.02f", setPeso).replace(',', '.'));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
```

Thanks a lot for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
editPeso.setText(String.format("%.02f", setPeso).replace(',', '.'));
```

with

```
editPeso.setText(String.valueOf(setPeso));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
editPeso.setText(String.format("%d", setPeso));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) parameters:

```
'f'  floating point: The result is formatted as a decimal number
'd'  integral:       The result is formatted as a decimal integer
```